# Don’t you need to prove operations in algebra are functions first?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, solution-verification, proof-explanation

In algebra when we do the same thing to both sides of an equation it’s like you’re putting each side of the equation through the same function, right? **Don’t you need to prove that this operation to each side of the equation is a function first?**

So when you take the square root of each side of an equation for example you need to prove that it’s a well defined operation or function first, don’t you?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: So is this what is done in real analysis? It seems you can’t do basic algebra without proving a lot more prerequisite material.

Comment: @Charmander71790 This is a fundamental property of equalities called the [substitution property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)#Basic_properties): "*for any quantities a and b and any expression F(x), if a = b, then F(a) = F(b) (provided that both sides are well-formed)*".

Comment: Don’t you need to know if something like square root is a function F(x) first? I’ve been told it’s a function but I haven’t proved it’s one myself.

Comment: @Charmander71790 That falls into the "*provided that both sides are well-formed*" part of the quote. $a=b \implies \sqrt{a}=\sqrt{b}$ *provided that* both make sense in whatever context you are working in.

Comment: @Charmander71790 yes, **everything** has to be proved, and things like "square root function is well and uniquely defined" is a mathematical theorem that has a proof. And yes, you can't work with stuff that have not been proven (well, it's a grey area anyway). If some  book uses facts without proof, then it should either refer to some other book that contains proof or it is a well known fact (like the one about square root function). So well established that no longer requires explanation. Still, a beginner should search for a proof. For example here on math stackexchange. :)